# using splat function and a for loop to pass multiple function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add two keys,values from one dict to a new dict. 
I know there are easier alternatives for this task but I'm trying to learn how to pass parameters in a single line.

```
    colors = {'col1' : 'Red', 'col2' : 'Blue', 'col3' : 'Yellow'}
    colors_new = dict.fromkeys( *(x,colors[x]) for x in ['col1','col2'] )
    print(colors_new)
```

Error
    File "", line 5
        colors_new = dict.fromkeys( *(x,colors[x]) for x in ['col1','col2'] )
                                                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

expected output:

```
{'col1': 'Red', 'col2': 'Orange'}
```

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in colors.items() if k in {'col1', 'col2'}}` ?

Comment: thank you for your comment, I am sorry I was unclear before. I edited and added the line "I know there are easier alternatives for this task but I'm trying to learn how to pass parameters in a single line."

Comment: i only wrote a "single line"

Comment: but you didn't pass it as arguments to a function.

Comment: what function? .

Comment: the fromkeys method(function) from this example

Comment: Your line works if you just add parentheses `colors_new = dict.fromkeys( *((x,colors[x]) for x in ['col1','col2']) )` but I don't know if that is what you want.

Comment: what you're asking is unclear, `dict.fromkeys()` isn't the right choice here, you could use the `dict()` construction (e.g. `dict((k,v) for k,v in colors.items() if k in {'col1', 'col2'})`), but the dict comphrnesion is better

Comment: It's working but it's pretty clearly not what I want, ```{'col1': 'Red', 'col2': 'Orange'}``` this is what I want

Comment: @Chris_Rands I understand this, I'm just trying to learn how to pass it to a method for learning not implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unpacking operators `*` and `**` are very situational - in this case, only really useful in calling functions. The problem here is *what* you're unpacking: just the tuple, rather than the entire list comprehension.

You're getting a `SyntaxError` because the tuple you're trying to unpack isn't in a context where it can be unpacked properly (and python has no idea what you're trying to do by doing a `for` loop afterwards). This is because it isn't directly inside the function call - it's inside the *generator comprehension*, which is itself inside the function call).

One alternative you could maybe do is add another set of parentheses:

```
colors_new = dict.fromkeys( *((x,colors[x]) for x in ['col1','col2']) )
```

which is equivalent to calling

```
colors_new = dict.fromkeys(('col1','Red'), ('col2','Blue'))
# colors_new = {'col1': ('col2', 'Blue'), 'Red': ('col2', 'Blue')}
```

This is not what you want to do, and results from a misunderstanding of `dict.fromkeys()`:

```
fromkeys(iterable, value=None, /) method of builtins.type instance
    Create a new dictionary with keys from iterable and values set to value.
```

`dict.fromkeys` takes exactly two arguments, and initializes all keys to the same value. If you were to pass an extra argument in, you'd get an error.

---

If you want to initialize a `dict` with different keys set to different values, then there are a few ways to do that. For one, just using the `dict` constructor with 2-tuples will work (no need for the unpacking uperator):

```
colors_new = dict((x, colors[x]) for x in ['col1', 'col2'])
# {'col1': 'Red', 'col2': 'Blue'}
```

Or you could use a `dict` comprehension, which is perhaps more elegant and more clear:

```
colors_new = {k:v for k,v in colors.items() if k in {'col1', 'col2'}}
# {'col1': 'Red', 'col2': 'Blue'}
```

Comment: Isn't `col2` supposed to be `Orange`? ;)

Comment: @Justin in OP's example yes, but OP's code gives no indication of why that should be (considering `Orange` isn't anywhere in the `colors` dict)

Comment: Don't worry, I was just playing around... ;) Nice answer!